# Intentionally not returning Bluebird Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, bluebird

I have the piece of code below. Want to call the callback which may return a promise. Resolve it. In case if the promise failed, log it. The caller should NOT know about all this and should return without waiting for the promise to fulfill. That's why I'm not returning the promise. This causes the following error:

```
(node:21146) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at internal/timers.js:456:21 but was not returned from it, see http  goo.gl/rRqMUw
    at Function.Promise.cast (bluebird/js/release/promise.js:225:13)
```

I've read the docs and they recommend returning null to prevent the warning from happening. Nevertheless, the warning still pops out. Also, do not want to disable the warning globally.

```
    private _trigger(cb : () => Resolvable<any>)
    {
        try
        {
            const res = cb();
            const prom = Promise.resolve(res);
            prom.catch(reason => {
                this.logger.error("ERROR: ", reason);
            })
        }
        catch(reason)
        {
            this.logger.error("ERROR: ", reason);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you add a no-op `.then()` handler?

Comment: Where Bluebird is installed, keep global reference to javascript's native Promise, say `Promise_`, then in `_trigger()`, write `Promise_.resolve(res)`.

Comment: I tried   .then(() => null); as suggested but didnt help

Comment: @Roamer-1888, could you elaborate on this bit more?

Comment: @rubenhak, it's just a suggestion. I haven't tested it. You should be able to try out the idea from what I say above. It''s not hard.

Answer (score 1):

The internal Promise should *resolve* to a value of `null` to silence the warning - this will tell Bluebird "*The Promise isn't being returned, but since it resolves to null, it doesn't contain a useful result, so this is deliberate*"; returning it wouldn't give the caller useful data. You can do something like:

```
const prom = Promise.resolve(res)
  .catch(reason => {
    this.logger.error("ERROR: ", reason);
  })
  .then(() => null);
```

Comment: Does it mean I dont need the "return null;" inside the caller function?

Comment: That's right, since the `_trigger` isn't inside a Promise's `.then`, you don't need to `return null` from it

Comment: I dont have good explanation, but I'm still getting the same warning....